# How to play sound on Tizen Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, audio, tizen

```
Tizen.NET 6.0.0.14995
Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI 1.4.0
Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer 1.4.0
Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.908675
```

A simple task is to play a sound on some event.
Now I look towards "SimpleAudioPlayer"
I have a resource

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="sound-active.mp3" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="sound-active.mp3" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

I use the following code to initalize:

```
Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
{
      var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
      var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);

      return stream;
}

private void InitSound()
{
    var stream = GetStreamFromFile("MyApp.sound-active.mp3");
    soundActive = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
    soundActive.Load(stream);
}
```

But soundActive for some reason is null.

It seems to me that some kind of plugin initialization is missing. Or the library is simply outdated, although the number of downloads is high. Can someone advise how to solve this seemingly simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I converted MP3 files to wav, put them in "res" directory

```
        /  AppName
AppName
        \ AppName.Tizen.Wearabe / res
```

To play the sound I use the following code:

```
string GetPathToSound(string soundName)
{
    return "/opt/usr/home/owner/apps_rw/org.app.test/res/" + soundName;
}

...

WavPlayer.StartAsync(GetPathToSound("sound-active.wav"), new AudioStreamPolicy(AudioStreamType.Media));
```

Comment: What was the tag in your "Wearable" csproj to correctly get it to ship with your exe? When I add a file it defaults to Not include.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. In which file can I see the information you need?

Comment: it's ok, I found the solution.